# Cloudflare cached things without Cache-Control and Expires header by default

Tags: cloudflare

From the [doc](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior):

> Cloudflare caches the resource in the following scenarios:
>
> - The Cache-Control header is set to public and the max-age is greater than 0.
> - The Expires header is set to a future date.

But I find it cached my js files, even when my nginx server doesn't send any Cache-Control and Expires header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cloudflare caches the resource in the following scenarios:

This is a bulleted statement from the first paragraph on this [page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior) which, as the beginning of this paragraph explains, applies to the case when there are headers sent by your server.

In other words, when there is a non-default case with the headers supplied by your server, Cloudflare treats the headers according to the bulleted points specified in the first paragraph.

> But I find it cached my js files

When there are no headers (which you are referring to by saying *"my nginx server doesn't send any Cache-Control and Expires header"*) then this is the default case and the second paragraph on the same [page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior) applies. It says that .JS files are cached by default.

Comment: I thought Cache-Control and file extensions have to be satisfied at the same time to let cloudflare cache. My bad understanding. By the way, do you know what the Edge Cache TTL is for these file extensions if there is no Cache-Control headers? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It's quite logical to assume that `Edge Cache TTL` determines caching duration e.g. for how long CF Edge Cache keeps your file. That's what I initially thought as well. Now I'm inclined to think that `Edge Cache TTL` setting controls the upper limit of the caching timeframe with the actual caching duration being entirely at CF disposal. The setting seems to be called in the past `Edge Cache Expire TTL`, see this [blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/edge-cache-expire-ttl-easiest-way-to-override/) written by CF cofounder which lends credibility to this theory. She called it that way for a reason.

Comment: The defaults are not documented, maybe the min values documented [there](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/edge-browser-cache-ttl#edge-cache-ttl) are the defaults.

Comment: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/configure-cache-status-code/#edge-ttl

The upper limit is documented here. The default ttl for 200 code is 120m.